# Datatables sort by time ago

Tags: javascript, sorting, datetime, datatable

I have a table where a column is listed all dates but it doesn't sort correctly..

I used livestamp.js and moment.js to make the date as time ago for easy reading..
instead of `3/1/2012` it will be `2 years ago` You just need to convert it to timestamp.

here is the complete [**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kaqp4c9v/)

as you can see by clicking on the modified column, it doesn't sort correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you are not getting the desired sorting because it is being ordered lexicographycally.

You can take advantage of the [HTML5 `data` attributes](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html), like you do with the `livestamp.js`, to use the timestamp representation for sorting.

Simply add the `data-order` attribute to every timestamp cell:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>ITEM 1</td>
        <td data-order="1416934028"><span data-livestamp="1416934028"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ITEM 2</td>
        <td data-order="1415033228"><span data-livestamp="1415033228"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ITEM 3</td>
        <td data-order="1401900428"><span data-livestamp="1401900428"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ITEM 4</td>
        <td data-order="1330620428"><span data-livestamp="1330620428"></span></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

See the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/kaqp4c9v/5/) updated.

Comment: thank you.. now my project will be easy.. thanks again.

Comment: This only works for tables where the rows are controlled by the user. If you let datatables build the entire table this will not work :(